# kotlin lambda is invalid for custom java functional interface

Tags: java, kotlin

Kotlin lambda is valid for JDK built-in functional interface:

```
// These are OK:
fun <T> ((T) -> Boolean).asJavaFun(): Predicate<T> = Predicate { this(it) }
fun <T, U> ((T, U) -> Boolean).asJavaFun(): BiPredicate<T, U> = BiPredicate { it0, it1 -> this(it0, it1) }
```

But it is invalid for custom functional interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface IndexedPredicate<T> {
    fun test(index: Int, t: T): Boolean
}
// This is wrong: interface IndexedPredicate does not have constructors
// And it recommends: convert to anonymous object
fun <T> ((Int, T) -> Boolean).asJavaFun(): IndexedPredicate<T> = IndexedPredicate { i, it -> this(i, it) }
```

Why and how to solve?

Comment: Kotlin interfaces are only treated as functional interfaces if you put the `fun` keyword in front of them.

Comment: @Tenfour04 You're right! Add an answer I can pick you